# how to create folder under source folder in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

i had created normal_folder under source_folder but it is created as package. once go through the picture, in that,i had created messages_folder under com/intern-bridge/resources but it is created as package.

1. why this happened?
2. how to create folder under source_folder i.e under com/intern-bridge/resources?
3. why i'm unable to create normal_folder under source folder?

The project view:

[image: please see project_view picture.]

Comment: Most likely it is created as folder. But you are *looking* at it using the package explorer, and thus the folder is showing up as package?!

Comment: but i'm unable to access files i.e .properties files from this folder

Comment: You can reconfigure this in Eclipse, but normally you shouldn't. You do not use "normal" folders in the source folder, just packages.

Comment: Copy/Paste a folder from another place to resources then rename it

Comment: I tried this with right click -> new -> folder and it just worked, I now have a test folder in my src/main/resources folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @GhostCat says in your comment section you're probably just looking at the `Package Explorer`.

To view the `Navigation Explorer`, open any file in your project, left click on the `Navigate` tab in eclipse, go to `show in` then select `Navigator`. This shoulod open the `Navigator` tab on the left and show your folder system.

Hope this helps! Let me know how it goes!

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue, this was done inside the package explorer without an issue (I usually use the project explorer personally) -> https://i.gyazo.com/a6c28fafebfb9116d3b67f1cc46393d7.png

Comment: I know, just the way I read his question it sounded to me like, as was already said, he probably had created a folder just wasn't happy how it was appearing on his screen. I use both package explorer and navigator, depending on what I need to see at that time.

Comment: @wep0n  i had done this before as what u had did, even though it is not applicable. with help of this answer, i can able to view folder in navigator_tab. actually i have viewed files in project_explorer_tab but it have to be in navigator_tab. sorry guys for silly mistake i had made thanks for your solution

Comment: but in this view i.e navigator_tab, every thing (i.e even package also seems like folder) seems in folder.but why i'm unable to view as folder in project_explorer_tab. what would be reason behind it. @Ryry